# How to create a hash for all records created by a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In our Rails app, the user (or we on his behalf) load some data or even insert it manually using a crud.

After this step the user must validate all the configuration (the data) and "accept and agree" that it's all correct.

On a given day, the application will execute some tasks according the configuration.

Today, we already have a "freeze" flag, where we can prevent changes in the data, so the user cannot mess the things up...

But we also would like to do something like hash the data and say something like "your config is frozen and the hash is 34FE00...".

This would give the user a certain that the system is running with the configuration he approved.

How can we do that? There are 7 or 8 tables. The total of records created would be around 2k or 3k.

How to hash the data to detect changes after the approval? How would you do that?

I'm thinking about doing a find_by_user in each table, loop all records and use some fields (or all) to build a string and hash it at the end of the current loop.

After loop all tables, I would have 8 hash strings and would concatenate and hash them in a final hash.

How does it looks like? Any ideas?

Comment: I did not get it - you expect user to read through 3k DB entries?

Comment: I would use auditing instead. Use something like [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) that keeps a record of the changes and let users roll back bad changes instead.

Comment: No Andrey, the user won't read all the rows. Some of the data are generated by us. Only a small part of the data is provided from the user... Imagine the user should provide us a product catalog, a list of categories, etc... After we import these he must validate and we would freeze the configuration.

hashA = TableA.findByUser.all.map{|e| e.field_a + e.field_b}.to._s.to_md5
hashB = TableB.findByUser.all.map{|e| e.field_a + e.field_b}.to._s.to_md5
...
final_hash = (hashA + hashB + hashN).to_md5

Comment: Max, actually I don't want to allow changes. And want to use a "hash" to identify any violation...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation. Just define `object` as an Array of all the stuff you'd like to hash :

```
require 'digest/md5'

def validation_hash(object, len = 16)
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(object.to_json)[0,len]
end

puts validation_hash([Actor.first,Movie.first(5)])
# => 94eba93c0a8e92f8
# After changing a single character in the first Actors's biography :
# => 35f342d915d6be4e
```